# Getting too many groups when sorting after grouping on spgridview?

Tags: 2010, filter, spgridview, grouping

When applying a sort on my spgridview after grouping, the sort does works but the groups are splited in many others labeled identically. For instance, if I have:

- group 1

  - 4
  - 2
- group 2

  - 3
- group 3

  - 1

After filtering on my column I get:

- group 1

  - 2
- group 1

  - 4
- group 2

  - 3
- group 3

  - 1

I have to specify that in order to get grouping working properly, I had to sort results on the column I'm grouping by. Obviously, I want to keep my three groups and sort on an other column. I'm aware of the "SPGridView doesn't allows multi-column sorting" thing. Can someone had this issue before and tell me how to solve this ? Thanks in advance.